# Como adicionar novos dados no JSON com TypeScript e Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, typescript

Eu tenho um JSON parecido com isso:

```
[
    {
        "texto": "Eae", 
        "contato": "Luis", 
        "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:00"
    },{
        "texto": "Salve povo", 
        "contato": "Rogerio", 
        "data": "2018-09-25T21:15:00"
    }
]
```

E um componente HTML com uma `textarea` onde o usuário digitaria o **texto** e os dados que faltam como **contato** e **data** são pegos dinamicamente.

Como eu faço para adicionar uma "mensagem" no JSON para que ele fique algo parecido com isso:

```
[
    {
        "texto": "Eae", 
        "contato": "Luis", 
        "data": "2018-09-25T21:08:00"
    },{
        "texto": "Salve povo", 
        "contato": "Rogerio", 
        "data": "2018-09-25T21:15:00"
    },{
        "texto": "De boas?", 
        "contato": "Victor", 
        "data": "2018-09-25T21:09:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentaste usar [Array.push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)?

Seria algo tipo:

```
meuArray.push({
    "texto": "De boas?", 
    "contato": "Victor", 
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:09:00"
});
```

ou então

```
var objetoComAsInformacoesDesejadas = {
    "texto": "De boas?", 
    "contato": "Victor", 
    "data": "2018-09-25T21:09:00"
};
meuArray.push(objetoComAsInformacoesDesejadas);
```

Comment: Eu estou tentando usar uma variável interna e privada, do tipo HttpClient
`this._http.get("../assets/db/mensagem.json");`


Teria algum método dela para enviar diretamente ao JSON?

Comment: Não entendi, amigo. O problema não era adicionar um item no array? Teu comentário sugere que o problema possa ser outro, não relacionado com a pergunta. Se for o caso, sugiro fazer uma nova pergunta, esclarecendo o problema, com exemplo de código mínimo que o reproduza.

Comment: Eu preciso que o dado digitado (**texto**) seja jogado dentro do JSON (o **contato** e **data** são pegos dinamicamente pela aplicação), por exemplo
Eu digito "Olá" na textarea e no JSON deve ser inserido uma nova "mensagem" :
`{
        "texto": "Olá", 
        "contato": "Victor", 
        "data": "2018-09-27T14:10:00"
    }`

Comment: Se é isso, o `Array.push` resolve. Basta criar um objeto com os elementos desejados [e o texto](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp) e fazer o push...

Comment: Se desejas transformar teu objeto em texto novamente, usa o [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)